# How to pass jpql to query method in spring jpa?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Our project involves hundreds of tables/entities, so it's boring to create a single repository for every entity. We want to create a generic repository for common query use which might have a below look:

```
@Repository
public interface GenericRepo extends JpaRepository<Ctmpdis,Integer> {
   public List findByQl(String jpql,Map params);
}
```

I want to pass concrete jpql to the method on the fly so that we don't have to create so many repos just need one to do all the variable queries.The problem of this idea is I don't know how to pass a query to repo and make it work. Does anybody know how to do it and is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a [custom repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories), here is an example

```
public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

  public List findByQl(String jpql,Map params);
}

public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

  public MyRepositoryImpl(Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(domainClass, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public List findByQl(String jpql,Map params) {
    // implementation goes here
  }
}
```